# React отправка формы с файлом

Tags: javascript, reactjs, form, fetch

Использовал fetch(), не вышло, пытаюсь через formData, тоже не выходит

```
let formData;
    handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    formData = {
        name: this.state.name,
        email: this.state.email,
        type: this.state.type,
        bodyText: this.state.bodyText,
        file: this.state.file,
    };
    {this.fetchForm()}
}



    fetchForm () {
    fetch('url', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: {formData}
    })

        .then(function () {
            console.log('bodyText -- ' , {data})
        })
        .then(function(body) {
            console.log('request succeeded with JSON response', body)
        }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('request failed', error)
    })
}


 <input className="form_submit" type="submit" value="Отправить сообщение" onClick={this.handleSubmit} />
```

Ответ

> POST url 400 (Bad Request)
>
> request succeeded with JSON response undefined

При это

> console.log('bodyText -- ' , {data})

Выводит ключ -> значение

Comment: попробуй сделать const sendData = new FormData(formData);